# Why does basic EventArgs class exist

Tags: c#, oop, events

this is more theoretical question. I know that every event in C# has to have 2 parameters: object and eventargs. It's clear. But why does the basic eventargs class even exist when it's impossible to pass any data with it? Of course I can make new EventArgs class that inherits from the basic one, but I just miss the point of the class that can't carry any data.

Comment: An event does not *have* to have these two parameters, only an event which is handled using a delegate which inherits from `EventHandler`.

Comment: @Rotem - close, but delegates don't inherit.

Comment: The pattern is a library/framework guideline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is about future-proofing your code.

The theory goes that if at some point you discover that your code should publish more data to event handlers than it did before, you can easily just add more properties to the object you pass to those event handlers.

If, for some reason, the class that holds those data is not under your control you inherit from it, and add your properties to the inherited class. So far so good.

But, if you never passed any object to the event handler in the first place, you cannot add a new parameter to the event delegate without existing code breaking.

As such, that you pass what amounts to a dummy object, `EventArgs.Empty` to events now give you the ability to later on inherit from EventArgs and start passing data to the same events, without having to change the event handlers at all. I most cases, you don't even have to recompile assemblies that uses the event handler.

So `EventArgs` is just a handy class you pass to event handlers, you could just as easily create your own, but since it has no meaning except to be a placeholder for possible future changes, there's no need to create your own, simply use `EventArgs`.

Comment: Ok, I get it but I still think it's a pity that I doesn't have any object property or something. Or is there such a class prepared?

Comment: EventArgs is pointless: This same result could have been achieved by passing an argument of type System.Object.  EventArgs.Empty could just as well have been a dummy System.Object instead of a dummy System.EventArgs.